# How can 3He be mined on the moon?

Tags: the-moon, mining, chemistry, helium-3

Now I know how it is detected, but what would the mining process be like? given that there is a lot on the moon but not concentrated, so you have to process large amounts of surface to extract a certain amount. Since Helium is a gas, what process should be applied to the surface to separate it?

Comment: The answer is [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/would-it-be-more-viable-to-process-moon-rocks-into-helium-3-on-the-moon-than-doi?rq=1), heating the rocks to about 600 °C. He3, not 3He, 3He means 3 atoms of He.

Comment: @Uwe: Unfortunately that's also ambiguous, think "H2O". "He-3" avoids that confusion, but is occasionally awkward (p-B-11 fusion, for example). Unicode superscript/subscript characters could do the job without relying on HTML or LaTeX (³He, H₂O), but that probably interferes with searching.

Comment: (n.b.: that's the first time I've seen the new auto-dup comment, and it's a much better one than the previous, though a bit weird to see!)   As far as superscript characters, I think they're fine to use here; but why not just *spell it out*?  We don't charge by the character here! :)